# Tic Tac Toe - Computer AI

Tags: c#

I'm building a 5x5 tic tac toe game between player and computer, and I run into the part where the computer will look at the player moves, and decide to block his winning turn if the player already has 4 in the row. So I know it should be a for loop, but I'm having problem to implement it. What is the best way to look for an array, that's gonna have 4 elements inside to check if 4 out of 5 elements in there are the same ? Normally I would do `if else` statement, but an `if else` in this case should be tedious and long.

Below is my pseudocode for this

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++)
{
     if(any 4 out of 5 elements are equal)
     {
          block it;
     }
}
```

PS: I have a winning combination array for the 5x5 and it has the row size of 12

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ:

```
if(elements.GroupBy(e=>e).Max(g=>g.Count())>=4)
  ...
```

`GroupBy` groups equal values together (as a collection of IGrouping), and `Max(g=>g,Count())` returns the number of items in the largest group.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode in C# style, being

`wins` an array of winning combinations array (by position) e.g. [[0,1,2,3], [1,2,3,4], ...]

`board` a single array of chars (e.g) with the 25 squares (5x5). e.g. each square can be ' ', 'X' or 'O'

`player` is either 'X' or 'O', for example.

This is the algorithm to check if a player wins.

```
bool checkWin(char player)
{
  foreach (win in wins)
  {
     int count = 0;
     foreach(sq in win)
     {
       if (board[sq] == player)
         count++;
     }
     if (count == 4) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: But does this cover diagonal wins?

Comment: Of course, supposing you have all the diagonal combinations arrays inside of `wins`. I have to say that `board` is just a single array of 25 elements.